# VBA macro for Google search

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, google-search

I am trying to modify a VBA macro for Google search. I want the output in excel to be the number of results (hits on Google). I have tried to change the element within the macro to "resultStats" but I keep getting bugs when I am trying to run it. The macro was at first made to gather weblinks for Google, which works perfectly.

So I though I only had to change the element in the script but this doesn't work.

Underneath I have posted the script.

Hope someone have an answer to my problem.

```
Sub Gethits()
    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date
    Dim var As String
    Dim var1 As Object

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
        Set var1 = html.getelementbyid("resultStats")
        Cells(i, 2).Value = var1.innerText

        DoEvents
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)                
End Sub
```

Comment: What excatly is your goal? how should the output look like? And what for Bugs are you getting?

Comment: My goals is the type in a words I want to know the number of results on in a Google search. When I run the script I get a error  in "Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementbyid("resultStats")(0)", (error 438 Object dosen't support this property or method). And the output should be the number of results(hits) in a Google search

Comment: `.getElementById` returns a single element, not a collection - so using `(0)` after it will cause an error.

Comment: Avoid the late-binding. Add a Reference to Microsoft XML v6.0, and you'll get Intellisense to help you

Comment: Thanks.
I have tried run without (0), however, now I get the error 91 "Object variable or With block variable not set". Any ideas?

Comment: @ThunderFrame I have added the reference, but still get the same error.

Comment: I done some changes and I think I'm almost there! However, I have some problems with getting the output. I have typed 'Cells(i, 2).Value = var1.innerText"', but I get the error 91 (Object variable or With block variable not set). 

Any ideas?

Comment: so, var1 is nothing (resultStats does not exists on page you got), thats why you are getting error message, if you print out html.body.innerhtml, youll probably have message that Your client does not have permission to get URL

Comment: your url is not correct, with correct url your code works

Comment: I have change the url, but I still get the same error "Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set. 

@tsolina did you run the script?

Comment: Never mind, I got it now! Thanks for the inputs!

Comment: yes i runned it

Comment: That seems to work fine.  What's the problem exactly?